# ValueError: Unrecognized character a in format string

Tags: python, dictionary, matplotlib, plot, valueerror

I have this data set that outputs strange error when I try to call its values. Unsure about where I am going wrong.
where data1 is the dictionary, it outputs the following error:

```
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py in _plot_args(self, tup, kwargs)
    310     def _plot_args(self, tup, kwargs):
    311         if len(tup) > 1 and isinstance(tup[-1], str):
--> 312             linestyle, marker, color = _process_plot_format(tup[-1])
    313             tup = tup[:-1]
    314         elif len(tup) == 3:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py in _process_plot_format(fmt)
    102             i += 2
    103         else:
--> 104             raise ValueError(
    105                 'Unrecognized character %c in format string' % c)
    106 

ValueError: Unrecognized character a in format string
```

I have extracted the type of both the dictionary and both value sets. The dictionary is a dict and the value sets for both are lists.

However, when I plot it the following way, it works:

```
plt.figure()
x= data1['date']
y = data1['value']
plt.plot(x,y)
```

What could be going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
    
d = { "name" : ["Joe", "Maria", "Anna", "Bob"], "gender" : ["Male", "Female", "Female", "Male"], "salary" :[10000,20000,24000,14000]}
 
plt.plot("name", "salary", data=d)
plt.show()
```

You have to pass in the parameter object so it can understand that you want the labels from the object. In your case it treat the `"date", "value"` as iterables because `string` is an `iterable` and it tries to set ticks "d", "a", "t", "e".

Answer (score 1):

You should pass variables instead:

```
plt.plot(date,value,data1)
```

Comment: When I try this I obtain NameError: name 'date' is not defined. According to this documentation: https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html I should be able to do it as plt.plot('date','value',data1) if its a callable object such as a dictionary